# Не загружается картинка с помощью CostaRico/yii2-images

Tags: php, yii2

использую CostaRico/yii2-images для вывода изображение записи из бд, но метод getUrl создает странную ссылку в итоге ссылка не существует в чем может быть проблема? 
Ссылка `http://tj/11/images/image-by-item-and-alias?item=Person77&dirtyAlias=3398c7a672-1_84x84.jpg`

---

[Нашел решение](https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images/issues/72)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, нужно в `vendor\costa-rico\yii2-images\models\Image.php` заменить `'/'.$this->getPrimaryKey().'/images/image-by-item-and-alias',` на `'/yii2images/images/image-by-item-and-alias', или '/'.$this->getModule()->id.'/images/image-by-item-and-alias',`